# How to check the time at which the command was executed?

Tags: bash, command-history, timestamps

When `history` command is executed, it shows a list of recently executed commands. Is there any provision with which we can see the time at which those particular commands were executed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to set the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` env variable.

From `help history`:

> ```
> If the $HISTTIMEFORMAT variable is set and not null, its value is used
> as a format string for strftime(3) to print the time stamp associated
> with each displayed history entry.  No time stamps are printed otherwise.
> ```

The format is described in the [strftime manpage](http://www.manpages.info/linux/strftime.3.html).

See examples [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/10/command-line-tricks-how-to-identify-date-and-time-of-a-unix-command-execution/) and [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-history-display-date-time/). The most useful one is probably

```
$ export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
$ history|tail -2
501  2014-11-03 20:51:41 export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
502  2014-11-03 20:51:44 history
```

Comment: Try to add a bit more information from the link.